# Map class to tables with different table names but same column structure

Tags: c#, linq

I have over 10 SQL Tables with the same column structure but different table names. I want to be able to use LINQ to work with the data in the tables. Is it possible to create a class that models the table structure like I normally do but just not define the table name? Is there a way to use LINQ with tables that have the same structure but different names?

Comment: I guess Entity Framework would map the tables for me wouldn't it?

Comment: With EF Code First you can map the entity to different tables dynamically.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with EF, sounds good. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With EF Code First you can map the entity to different tables dynamically:

```
public class OrderContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _tableName;

    public OrderContext(string tableName)
        : base("name=OrderContext")
    {
        _tableName = tableName;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().ToTable(_tableName);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var orders = new OrderContext("Orders").Orders;
var legacyOrders = new OrderContext("LegacyOrders").Orders;
```

Comment: So with this I don't have to use the EF wizard? I just pass in the name of the table to create the collection?

Comment: @JonKittell: Welcome to the wonderful and weird world of Code First approach! :) You don't have XML/EDMX file, all your mappings happen in C# code.

Comment: That is awesome, I have used the wizard in ASP.NET MVC but really didn't want to use it in this Windows Forms Application. Very cool!

Comment: Yeah, wizard is a mess. It will go away anyway in next major version of EF (codename v7).